# Emacs won't highlight

Tags: emacs, fedora

I've just installed Fedora 23 and I've encountered a problem I've never seen in many years of using Emacs.

Emacs won't allow me to highlight text.  I noticed it first when trying to click-and-drag with the mouse, but then I tested it by setting the mark and moving the cursor - no highlighting.

The `<drag-mouse-1>` command description indicates that dragging should set a region and highlight text.  Transient-mark-mode is enabled, and I'm running Emacs in its own (non-terminal) window.  I can't find any other information about this.  Any ideas?

Edit: On closer inspection, I can act on the region that I try to highlight as normal (cutting, copying, etc.).  It seems like Emacs IS highlighting, it's just not SHOWING the highlighting.  A less serious problem, but one I'd still like to fix and don't know how.

Comment: Are you using a theme? Or a terminal that does not offer full color support? Can you still act on the region even if it is not highlighted?

Comment: @Jules Tamagnan - It's a fresh install, so if there's a theme I didn't do it.  I haven't even edited .emacs yet.  I'm using gnome-terminal, but this Emacs was opened in its own window from outside the terminal.  And, it turns out, I CAN act on the region as if it were highlighted!   Can't believe I forgot to check that.  Editing post.

Comment: What if you change the region face with something like: `(set-face-attribute 'region nil :foreground "#FFFFFF" :background "#000000")`

Comment: What @JulesTamagnan suggested. Sounds like the highlight color is the same as or similar to your background color. Try `M-x list-faces-display` and look at face `region`.

Comment: I tried @Drew's suggestion first, and it worked.  `M-x list-faces-display` gives you a long list of text display options.  Selecting `region` allows you to set `Background` to, say, gray using the `Choose` button.  The region is now clearly highlighted in gray!  @Drew, if you want to write that up as an answer I'll accept it.  Thanks to you and @Jules Tamagnan!

Comment: how would I write the change to my .emacs file so it's not lost in my next emacs session?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sounds like the highlight color is the same as or similar to your background color. Try `M-x list-faces-display` and look at face `region`. That also provides you an entry point for changing any of the faces displayed - just click the face name to open Customize for the face.